# php mysql data from database input to contact form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, hidden, contacts

I need to put some predefined text into the hidden field in contact form and than send it to mail.
But its not showing in mail. Any help?
My form code is this:

```
<?php 
require('assets/dbconn.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM auctions WHERE id=$id");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<form  class="form" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action='action.php'>
<label for="email" class="label_text">E-mail:<span class="required_sign">*</span></label>
<input id="email" name="email" class="required" type="email" />
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $row['CodeFromDB']; ?>" />
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you add the code for when you're creating the email, too, please? Have you checked that it's being populated correctly in the form? Is it being passed in $_POST properly?

Comment: `<input></input>` is your problem.

Comment: The error is not in the "creating-mail.php" because it echoes me back nothing when I looking at the source code in mozilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the value attribute of the input [MDN Input Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

```
<input id="code" name="code" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['CodeFromDB']; ?>"/>
```

Also, verify that $row['CodeFromDB'] is not empty, either by echoing it, or using testing with php's empty() function.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. The value is of corse there, but it echoes me nothing. Why?

Comment: If $row['CodeFromDB'] is empty, there might be something wrong with your query. You can try this debug line

<pre><?php print_r($row); ?></pre>

and see what that gives you.

Comment: CodeFromDB is not empty. Im sure of it because I echoes it little higher on my weg page and it works fine.

Comment: What does the print_r($row) show?